# Autocomplete in .php framework doesn't seem to work any longer

Tags: php, autocomplete, qcodo

I have a basic Autocomplete and Add to the database function and , for some reason, it has stopped working completely and I don't get any useful information from Firebug or otherwise what could be the problem.

I am guessing it is something simple, but don't know where to look.

This is the library where I am making the call:

http://github.com/allyforce/AF-upload/blob/master/Library/Target1.class.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone found the right answer in terms of remvoing a QEvent.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you debugging on? Firefox displays Ajax errors correctly, but no others do unless you apply this patch (which will be in the next release of QCubed):
http://trac.qcu.be/projects/qcubed/ticket/432

Comment: I am debugging on Firefox.  I am not getting errors or at least not finding them.